# Tomcat console remote

Tags: java, tomcat7

I'm starting tomcat by cmd (Windows) then Tomcat opens a java window like a console, tomcat log when people login/logout and shows it in this "window". I want to access remotely this "window" screen while server is running to admin who is login/logout. I saw Jconsole and it don't show what I want. What is the alternative?

Comment: I think this is just a by-product of the logging mechanism in Tomcat. It looks like it is set up to log to a console - by changing the logging mechanism you can get it to log to a file, which you would be able to access remotely by a number of different ways

Comment: it is logging into a file but I want to see while running

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to manage the tomcat, i think you can try to use Tomcat manager which is built-in in Tomcat server. you can access to it with /manager/html. In addition, you can use remote desktop to your remote host as a alternative.

Comment: I know and I use tomcat manager but I like I said before I want to see the console log while running. Is remote desktop the only way?

Comment: if you use win7, i suggest you can try to open Telnet service and access it use powershell from remote.